# yocto populate_sdk has lots of warnings: package is not installable

Tags: sdk, package, installation, yocto

I'm using yocto 2.6 (thud) to customize my linux image and now I can use bitbake to generate an image with my own applications, the image runs well on the board.

Now I'm trying to populate the sdk and I do:

```
bitbake dey-image -c populate_sdk
```

then I have lots of warnings, like

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-dev : Depends: apt (= 1.2.24-r0.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: bash-dev
           Recommends: libcurl-dev but it is not installable
 hwmoniter-dev : Depends: hwmoniter (= git-r0.7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libmosquitto1-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
```

It seems that `populate_sdk` finally succeeded with warnings, the sdk (*.sh) is generate and it can be installed, but I can't find many header files I assumed to be there.

So what do the warnings mean? What's the difference between "**not going to be installed**" and "**not installable**"? How can I fix those warnings?

Thanks